# Using Var on a DbSet inside a Dbcontext , will it be treated as IEnumerable OR as IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web project, using database first approach. Now I have the following Context class:-

```
Public partial class IT360servicedeskEntities : DbContext
    {
        public IT360servicedeskEntities()
            : base("name=IT360servicedeskEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<TAccount> TAccounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TAccountStatu> TAccountStatus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TContactInfo> TContactInfoes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TGroup> TGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TLogin> TLogins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TOrganization> TOrganizations { get; set
```

; }

Now let say inside my model class I wrote the following:-

```
var test = context. TOrganizations;
var2 = test.Where(a=>a.id == 100);
```

So my question what will be the var type ? will it be treated as IEnumerable OR as IQueryable, in other words will my above code cause the Where clause to be performed inside the memory or inside the database ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `var t = test.Where(a=>a.id == 100)` it will return `IQueryable<TOrganization>`. In you case, the Where is IQueryable's extension method, call this method will operate the [Expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) but no cause to be performed inside the database. When you foreach the `t` or call the `t.ToList()`/`t.ToArray()` it will visit Expression tree and build sql string, then get data from database.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so does this means that dbset is basically an IQuerable ?

Comment: @johnG Yeah, The `DbSet<T>` implemented `IQueryable<T>`